# Prepare Statement with output parameter Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, prepared-statement, npgsql

With the code below I call a strored procedure with 2 input parameter and 1 out parameter, but I receive this error:

> Bind message supplies 3 parameters, but prepared statement “” requires
>   2

I used 2.1.0 version of Npgsql.dll, I tried the next version untill 3.0.0 
but the problem still remain.
I've to use .NET framework 3.5

```
NpgsqlConnection psgConnection = new NpgsqlConnection("<connection string>");
NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
psgConnection.Open();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "<stored name>";
cmd.Connection = psgConnection;
NpgsqlParameter par_in_iduser = new NpgsqlParameter("in_iduser", DbType.Int32);
par_in_iduser.Value = IdUser;
cmd.Parameters.Add(par_in_iduser);
NpgsqlParameter par_in_name = new NpgsqlParameter("in_name", DbType.String);
par_in_name.Value = Nome;
cmd.Parameters.Add(par_in_name);

NpgsqlParameter par_out_id_document_search = new NpgsqlParameter("out_id_document_search", DbType.Int32);
par_out_id_document_search.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
par_out_id_document_search.Value = 0;
cmd.Parameters.Add(par_out_id_document_search);

cmd.Prepare();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

return Int32.Parse(cmd.Parameters["out_id_document_search"].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Could it be that the out-parameter is not bound in the prepare? Have you tried moving the `prepare()` to before binding the out-param just to see if it works?

Comment: Yes, I tried but I receive "index out of range"